# Symfony 2 Can't solve Construct

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm getting this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException' with message 'Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 8 passed to Sonata\\MediaBundle\\Provider\\ImageProvider::__construct() must implement interface Imagine\\Image\\ImagineInterface, none given, called in
```

My service:

```
sonata.media.provider.cropper:
    class: %cmy_sonata_media.custom_class_cropper%
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.media.provider }
    arguments:
        - sonata.media.provider.cropper
        - @sonata.media.filesystem.local
        - @sonata.media.cdn.server
        - @sonata.media.generator.default
        - @sonata.media.thumbnail.format
        - ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
        - ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
        - @sonata.media.adapter.image.gd
        - @sonata.media.metadata.proxy
    calls:
        - [ setTemplates, [ { helper_thumbnail: SonataMediaBundle:Provider:thumbnail.html.twig, helper_view: SonataMediaBundle:Provider:view_image.html.twig } ] ]
```

My provider

```
class ImageCropperProvider extends ImageProvider
{

protected $imagineAdapter;

/**
 * @param string                                                $name
 * @param \Gaufrette\Filesystem                                 $filesystem
 * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\CDN\CDNInterface                  $cdn
 * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Generator\GeneratorInterface      $pathGenerator
 * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Thumbnail\ThumbnailInterface      $thumbnail
 * @param array                                                 $allowedExtensions
 * @param array                                                 $allowedMimeTypes
 * @param \Imagine\Image\ImagineInterface                       $adapter
 * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Metadata\MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata
 */
public function __construct($name, Filesystem $filesystem, CDNInterface $cdn, GeneratorInterface $pathGenerator, ThumbnailInterface $thumbnail, array $allowedExtensions = array(), array $allowedMimeTypes = array(), ImagineInterface $adapter, MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata = null)
{

    parent::__construct($name, $filesystem, $cdn, $pathGenerator, $thumbnail, $allowedExtensions, $allowedMimeTypes, $metadata);

    $this->imagineAdapter = $adapter;
}

public function getProviderMetadata()
{
    return new Metadata($this->getName(), $this->getName().'.description', false, 'SonataMediaBundle', array('class' => 'fa fa-crop'));
}
}
```

What i'm trying to do is to create identical ImageProvider. But I keep getting that error:
I tryed almost everything. But always ending with this error.
Maybe I miss something. Maybe my Service configuration is wrong.
But it's identical to ImageProvider. So it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like it was my api cache problem. Solved after clearing all cache.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget an argument in your parent's construct call:
$adapter should be between $allowedMimeTypes and $metadata

or null if you want to set it afterwards (...allowedMimeTypes, null, $metadata)

Comment: That didn't helped. Error occured in function __construct